# Agrupar linhas duplicadas Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Criei a query de onde tenho uma tabela Produtos e uma outra estoque (1:N) preciso somar o estoque de cada produto tem na tabela de estoque, Fiz a seguinte query:

```
select DISTINCT p.ID,IsNull(p.CodigoBarra, '') As 
CodBarra,IsNull(p.CodigoAlternativo, '') As 
CodAlt,p.Descricao,p.DescricaoAlternativa,f.Descricao as Fabricante, 
sum(est.EstoqueAtual) as EstoqueAtual, COUNT(est.EstoqueAtual) as 
QtdEsnderecosEstoque from produto p
inner join Fabricante f on f.ID = p.FabricanteID
left join EstoqueLoteLocalizacao est on est.ProdutoId = p.ID
where p.DataExclusao is null and p.EmpresaID = 3
group by p.ID,p.CodigoBarra,p.CodigoAlternativo,p.Descricao,p.DescricaoAlternativa,f.Descricao, est.EstoqueAtual
```

Esta **Query** me retorna o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu preciso é que ao invés de ele me dar os **2 registros**, ele **agrupe** e o estoque atual ali seja somado 4000 - -40 e me **exiba em 1 registro** só o valor de 3960

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você usa função agrupadora (como o `SUM`), ele vai levar em consideração todas as linhas que sejam diferenciadas pelo `GROUP BY`.

No caso, seu `GROUP BY` incluía em sua cláusula a coluna `est.EstoqueAtual`. Se você remover essa coluna do `GROUP BY`, ele irá agrupá-la e ela será somada conforme desejado.

Comment: Funcionou, Eu a havia colocado no Group By por que estava dando este erro: A coluna 'Fabricante.Descricao' é inválida na lista de seleção porque não está contida em uma função de agregação nem na cláusula GROUP BY.
porém o erro pelo q vi nao se encaixava a ela e eu coloquei no impulso mesmo,mas em fim, Muito Obrigado pela explicação

Comment: @EdenilsonBila essas coisas são muito difíceis de perceber, normalmente só um revisor externo para ver